Conditions for nonzero determinant of a special matrix indexed by pairs $(i,j)$: is $\det M$ zero only for $n=4$?
Let $M$ be an $n \choose{2}$ $\times$ $n \choose{2}$ matrix, where each row and column is indexed by $(i, j)$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. The $(i,j), (k,l)$ element (that is, the element in the $(i,j)$th row and the $(k,l)$th column) is given by
\begin{equation}
M_{(i,j), (k,l)} = (-1)^{\delta(i, l) + \delta(j, k) + \delta(i,k) + \delta(j,l) - 2\delta(i,k)\delta(j,l))},
\end{equation}
where $\delta(a,b)$ is a usual delta function ($1$ when $a = b$ and $0$ when $a \neq b$). That is, an element in $M$ is $1$ except when one of $(i,j)$ is included in $(k,l)$ but not both, in which case the element is $-1$.
Explicit calculation shows that up to $n = 14$, $\det{M} \neq 0$ except $n=4$. Is it possible to show that $\det M = 0$ only when $n = 4$ and non-zero otherwise?

The term with the $2$ here can be dropped, since $(-1)^{2k} = 1$.

Vladimir Lysikov answered a more general question that I posted here.
He proved that the statement indeed holds for any $n \neq 4$. Thank you all for the input!
